# How to make selected color or font with angular material dropdown?

Tags: angular, typescript, colors, angular-material

I would like to do a dropdown to be able to change the color of the background & font using angular material.
what's the best way to do that?

In the dropdown there would be several colors and when you choose a color the background changes, i made a beginning of code after I am blocked

I would also like to change the font with a dropdown

thank you.

**html**

```
<h1>Change Color</h1>

<div class="center">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Neutre</mat-label>
        <mat-select>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let color of colors">{{color.name}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**ts.file**

```
 selectedColor = '';

  colors = [
    {
      name: 'yellow',
      value: '#ffff00'
    },
    {
      name: 'red',
      value: '#ff3300'
    },
    {
      name: 'blue',
      value: '#0000ff'
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Neutre</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedColor">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let color of colors" [value]="color.value">{{color.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div [style.background-color]="selectedColor">...</div>
```

Comment: thanks but how can I change the background-color when I choose the color in the dropdown ?

Comment: <div [style.background-color]="selectedColor">...</div>